# Manual activation of new user accounts in Django

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I created a working "Log in with facebook" setup with django-allauth. However, I want those new user accounts that allauth creates to not be activated automatically.

Basically I want to activate all new accounts from the Django admin pages.

What would be a best practice solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: My best advice is to user a custom user model, (see the documentation)[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/], and the following (tutorial)[https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html] might help on how to go about it.

Comment: Thank you! Links are broken tho. Oh I see its the bracket, thanks

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Comment: Added the correct url, sorry

Answer (score 1):

How do you know that an account is activated or not? You need some kind of field in your `User` model.

Let's say that your field is called `is_activated`:

```
class User(BaseUser):
    is_activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and that's it. This field's default value will be `False` which means that a created user is not activated by default.

Then, you can add this field to the admin page and toggle it from there.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! So I'll have to extend the user model I take it. Cool. In my templates I use {% if user.is_authenticated %}. How do I make sure that "user.is_authenticated" returns "false" on all the accounts that don't have is_activated set to true? Or should I rewrite all the templates to also check for "is_activated"? Thanks!!

Comment: @Daggepagge you will have to create a custom permission class where you would override is_authenticated. The easiest way would be to change your if statements to this {% if user.is_authenticated and user.is_activated %}

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest what follows because when I made [cogofly](http://www.cogofly.com) I had this huge problem where some people (few but some of them do) click sometimes on "log in with google" and sometimes on "log in with facebook" and this is the same person! So be careful with that and this solution will help you to avoid such problem. The only thing to remember: **there's only one primary key for all social networks: the email**.

[Like it's written in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#s-extending-the-existing-user-model), I'd make a `OneToOne` link to the `User` model.
From this I would suggest this:

- precise the date of the first login
- precise the date of the last login
- precise if the account has been validated

Like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And make a social login model where you precise how the user logged in:

```
class SocialLogin(BaseModel):
    S_GOOGLE = 1
    S_FACEBOOK = 2

    TAB_S_LOGIN = {
        S_GOOGLE: _("Google"),
        S_FACEBOOK: _("Facebook"),
    }
    logged_in = models.IntegerField(
        choices=[(a, b) for a, b in list(TAB_S_LOGIN.items())],
        default=S_GOOGLE)
    date_first_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                            verbose_name=_('First login'))
    date_last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,
                                           verbose_name=_('Last login'))
    person = models.OneToOneField(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def logged_in_desc(self):
        return SocialLogin.TAB_S_LOGIN[self.logged_in]

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} / {}'.format(
            self.logged_in_desc(),
            description if self.description is not None else '?')
```

Answer (score 0):

A strightforward solution to this problem would be to utilize [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save) signal on original User model.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=User)
def set_new_user_inactive(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance._state.adding is True:
        instance.is_active = False
```

Hope that helps!